# Redirect an usert after get information

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I'm trying to redirect to the user after of do an API process, I have this error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: Cannot access 'redirect' before initialization
    at HTMLFormElement.<anonymous> (completedetails.js:18)
(anonymous) @ completedetails.js:18
async function (async)
(anonymous) @ completedetails.js:16
```

I'm not sure why it is happening, the process of the API is working, the problem is at the moment of the redirect to the user with the submit buton

I'm leaving my JS code

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    console.log('Document is ready');
    const $form = document.querySelector('#completedetails');
    const $inputName = document.querySelector('#name');
    const $inputPassword = document.querySelector('#password');
    const $inputCompany = document.querySelector('#company');
    const $btn_completedetails = document.querySelector('#btn-completedetails');

    const url = "http://localhost:3000/register/";

    $form.addEventListener('submit', async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        let name = $inputName.value;
        let password = $inputPassword.value;
        let company = $inputCompany.value;
        const response = await fetch(`${url}${company}${name}${password}`, { method: 'POST' });
        const result = await response.json();
        return const redirect = await redirect('http://seth.com/dashboard.html?ftime=1');

        
        
    })
})
```

Comment: You don't appear to have defined `function redirect(to) { ... }` anywhere...

Comment: Oh and the `const redirect =` would be masking that function even if you had defined it.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol I'm near or that I think, I'm trying with it:
   await function redirect(to) { 
        redirect('http://seth.com/dashboard.html?ftime=1');
     }

Comment: Not even close. What is `redirect` supposed to be? If you are redirecting to another page, `await` will never resolve anyway.